# php Passing a variable in a URL with value not equal to

Tags: php, url

I am following this PHP tutorial for getting hold of some basic PHP stuff -> 
http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php.

Here it says that if we enter an URL like this:-> http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe, it will pass value "Joe" to the variable "name" of the page.php script.

This makes me wonder if we can pass multiple names (except that of Joe) to page.php script via something like http://html.net/page.php?name!=Joe ? Is this legal syntax or is there another way of achieving this.

Comment: no ... in short, though this is not a PHP thing but a part of the URL specification  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: that said you can pass in something like this  `http://html.net/page.php?not_name=Joe`  and then you just code it knowing that it's `not_name` of `Joe` ... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. To achieve that you could send the exclusions on another variable name called "exclusions" and then have some sort of filtering on the serverside.

Like this:
http://html.net/page.php?name=Maria,Peter&exclusions=Joe

Comment: Id use the array syntax for multiple names `http://html.net/page.php?name[]=Maria&name[]=Peter&exclusions=Joe`  That's just me though.

Answer (score 2):

No You can't pass like this. But if you want to comapre the value. You can pass extra query string param which indecates whether to match value or doesn't  match.
For example:

```
http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe&match=0
```

**Which indecates you want result with name = "Joe" (if match = 0)**

and

```
http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe&match=1
```

**Which indecates you want result with name != "Joe" (if match = 1)**